# Is there a standard make new pair?

Tags: c++, std-pair

I want a `pair<A,B>*`. `make_pair(a,b)` will give me a `pair<A,B>` (note the pair isn't a pointer). Is there a standard way to make a pair pointer? I tried adding new before after and in between the two words and it doesn't appear to exist.

Comment: Besides `auto p = new pair<A,B>(a,b);` I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't. You can roll your own:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
std::pair<typename std::decay<X>::type, typename std::decay<Y>::type>*
heap_pair(X&& x, Y&& y) {
  typedef typename std::decay<X>::type decayed_X;
  typedef typename std::decay<Y>::type decayed_Y;
  return new std::pair<decayed_X, decayed_Y>(
    std::forward<X>(x),
    std::forward<Y>(y)
  );
}
```

But you might want to add allocator customization to it.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of make_pair in gcc 4.6.2 I'm unsure this is 100% correct as it does not work with reference wrappers.

Comment: @ildjarn Realized after posting and double checked. Should be fixed now, besides the issue I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: The return type is still missing `decay<>`, and you're missing some `typename`s. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn Bah, I really should compile things beforehand instead of blindly typing.